# Semicolon (;) no ECMAScript 6 não é mais necessário?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Quando utilizamos o ECMAScript 6 (ES6) não é mais necessário a utilização de ponto e vírgula (;) no final de cada linha de código?

Comment: Entendo que é duplicata por dois motivos: como confirmado pelas respostas dadas, o comportamento da versão 6 não mudou a situação, e lá está extensivamente explicada não só se há obrigatoriedade ou não, como também as situações diversas que podem se desdobrar da falta do uso.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O **ponto e virgula** (semicolon) nunca foi obrigatório no final de linhas, o uso dele é outro, ele tem como objetivo separar expressões *que estão na mesma linha* ou dentro de um `for`.

Note que no *JavaScript* as quebras de linha também tem efeito de separar, veja:

```
var i = 0; i++ // ponto e virgula é obrigatório

var i = 0      // ponto e virgula é opcional pois estão em linhas diferentes
    i++
```

> **Nota ¹:** o `for` possui 3 expressões como explicado pelo @Sergio e por isto necessita dos dois `;`:
>
> ```
> for ([inicialização]; [condição]; [expressão ao final de cada loop])
> ```
>
> o `for` só não usa o `;` quando usa o `in` (a não ser que queria adicionar expressões para operações adicionais):
>
> ```
> for ([variável] in [objeto que terá as propriedades iteradas])
> ```
>
> ou `of`:
>
> ```
> for ([variável] of [objeto que terá os valores iterados])
> ```
>
> **Nota ²:** Isso ocorre em outras linguagens também

Fontes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: dentro do `for` não funciona sem o ponto e virgula...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues depende, ser for um `for()` com `in` é sem ponto e virgula, se for o `for` normal tem `;`. Ou você está querendo dizer que o meu texto está dando a entender algo errado?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ou `for... of` também é sem ponto e vírgula. E, como dito nos comentários na resposta abaixo, quando `;` não delimita, `;` é um statement. Por exemplo: `umaLabel: ;`, `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ; ; ;`, `for (const{}of[]) ;`, isso é como a maioria dos interpretadores interpretam: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%3B

Comment: @Phanpy ou eu não estou entendendo, ou tem algum erro no meu texto, delimita até aonde sei é dentro do contexto "limitar", eu disse separar, o que ao meu ver é diferente. statement significa "declaração", o que não me parece muito longe de expressão (termo que usei na resposta). Mas se eu tiver entendido algo errado por favor me oriente. Grato

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, correto! Acho que acabei misturando termos entre as duas respostas :/

Comment: @Phanpy obrigado pela dica do `for ... of`, vou editar e adicionar ;)

Answer (score 7):

Não tem a ver com `ES6` usar ou não ponto e virgula ou não, é "uma questão de religião" :)
Ou seja: É uma questão de estilo de código.

O `;` é um simbolo com funcionalidade em JavaScript, o de separar *statements*, nalguns casos não se pode ignorar, por exemplo: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, mas no final de linha é opcional, desde que haja uma quebra de linha.

Comment: Na realidade, `;` também é um statement, por exemplo: `label: ; for (;;) ;`. Ambas boas respostas

Comment: @Phanpy o `;` não é um _statement_, mas delimita statements, mesmo statements vazios. Ou seja um statement, só é um statement depois de `;` ter sido usado, ou quebra de linha na ausência de `;`. Talvez fosse isso que querias dizer também :)

Comment: Sim, `;` delimita statements. Quando ele delimita statements, ele não se torna um statement, mas se torna quando não delimita: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%3B . E você pode ver que labels requerem um statement na frente, por isso `label: ;` esse código é valido. Ah! E blocos não são delimitados por `;`: http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=%7B%7D%3B . Quando ver o link, você vai ver que o Esprima vai mostrar um `EmptyStatement` na árvore!

Comment: @Phanpy acho que isso é bug :D Eu percebo que na prática é assim, mas prefiro separar e dizer que um `;` confirma o empty statement, e não cria.

Comment: @Phanpy não conhecia esse parser, boa dica!. Dá uma olhada a este se não conheces: https://astexplorer.net/ é excelente e dá para fazer codemods.

Comment: Parece totalmente com o Esprima (ele faz o mesmo com os `;`) ! Agora só falta corrigir um erro de nomes reservados escapados com \u (que já foi corrigido no Esprima, mas a versão das demos não foi atualizada ainda) :-)

Comment: @Phanpy manda-lhes um PR, é malta do facebook que fez, são bons contactos :)