# Qual é a vantagem do ponto e vírgula em linguagens de programação?

Tags: c#, vb.net, desempenho, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Sei que em linguagens de programação como Java e C#, o ponto e vírgula indica o fim da instrução, como no exemplo abaixo, em C#:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

Porém, ainda sim existem linguagens em que o ponto e vírgula não é necessário (e nem possível), como no caso do Visual Basic, F#, Go, entre muitas outras.

- Qual é a vantagem de se indicar o fim das instruções?
- No caso do C#/VB, indicar o fim da instrução faz do C# mais performático
  que o VB.NET na [compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118707/41056)?

Comment: Relacionado [**Semicolon (;) no ECMAScript 6 não é mais necessário?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/174178/3635) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não muda na performance, isso é apenas sintático, sequer é semântico.

A primeira vantagem óbvia é que permite que instruções ([*statements*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101)) possam ser escritas em mais de uma linha, o que pode organizar melhor e deixar o código mais legível em algumas situações. Essa é uma forma de dar um ponto final na "frase". Ao mesmo tempo permite mais de um *statement* na mesma linha.

Algumas linguagens preferiram estabelecer que só poderia ter uma linha e o indicador de nova linha marca o final da "frase".

Claro que é possível ter outras soluções para essa necessidade, como indicar um marcador específico quando precisar continuar em outra linha.

Outra vantagem menos óbvia é a redundância. Por incrível que pareça redundância em código pode torná-lo mais confiável que está expressando a ideia certa e evita cometer erros por algum descuido. Além disso o compilador pode identificar erros mais facilmente e talvez dar uma mensagem mais próxima do que precisa para corrigir. É possível dar boas mensagens sem ter um terminador de instrução, mas complica bastante o compilador.

O mesmo ocorre com o humano que vai ler. Ter algo visual que mostre que a instrução encerrou ajuda os olhos dar um "parse" no texto.

E não podemos deixar de considerar a vantagem de que linguagens populares usam há muito tempo, e ter algo que as pessoas já estão acostumadas ajudam a aceitação de novas linguagens.

Escrever compiladores para linguagens sem terminação explícita do *statement* é mais difícil, então é uma vantagem para o outro lado, o dos escritores de compiladores :)

Mas eu acho mais limpo sem ele. Acho que polui e geram erros sem necessidade em muitos casos porque a pessoa esqueceu de colocar o terminador. Ser mais limpo não quer dizer que é melhor, mas é indiscutível que menos informação é algo mais limpo. Claro que limpeza demais pode trazer outros problemas. Quando a limpeza tira a proteção pode ser ruim.

Mas se a linguagem foi criada para usá-lo, deve usar, mesmo que seja opcional. Estou falando do JavaScript que as pessoas agora "resolveram" que não precisam mais do ponto e vírgula.

Há brigas religiosas por causa deste e outros tópicos de sintaxe de linguagens de programação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Há brigas religiosas por causa deste e outros tópicos de sintaxe de linguagens de programação" Infelizmente é verdade.Tem gente que prefere linguagens sem terminação (explícita) de linha e brigam por besteira. Pessoalmente tenho programado nos últimos 30 anos de basic num Z80 até C# passando por Java, Delphi, VB6, Borland C, Javascript com um pouco de PHP, Haskell... eu pessoalmente acho linguagens com "final de linha" tem uma sintaxe mais organizada e limpa.

Comment: @jean nosso *background*  é incrivelmente semelhante. Faltou Clipper para você :P Eu aproveitei e editei para discordar um pouco de você, sem tirar a sua razão :P

Comment: Blz, adoro debater sem dogmatismos. Eu acho que (com;) fica mais limpo no sentido de falta de dubiedade. Sim brinquei um pouco com assembly, clipper, cobol, a lista é grande =). Agora temos strings com @ no C#t e pra mim era a única coisa que faltava =D

Comment: Em ADVPL (Totvs) indica uma continuação de linha ...

Comment: @Motta Na verdade desde o Clipper. Não lembro se o dBase aceitava, acho que não. È o que eu falei no 4o. parágrafo de forma genérica.

Comment: Só quis dar um pitaco aí vc está alterando um advpl e uma function plsql ao mesmo tempo o ; vira um inimigo ...  :)