# Não colocar ponto e virgula no final da operação javascript é padrão do ES6?

Tags: javascript

vejo gente programando da seguinte forma:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

e

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

não colocar a virgula no final é padrão do Es6 mesmo? encontrei outra pergunta aqui na comunidade mas nas respostas não diz que é um padrão do ecma. Vi programadores dizendo que é padrão do Es6 e por isso me surgiu a dúvida. Não encontrei documento com essa afirmação.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186838/101

Comment: Em geral, não, não é padrão, o melhor ao meu ver é utilizar... mas, porém e todavia, vai de gosto de quem está codificando